# Quel(le) phrase/verbe pour exprimer "busy myself with" ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, phrase

Je sais que je peux dire, par exemple,

> Si tu as besoin de moi, je vais m'occuper dans le jardin

Mais je ne suis pas sûr que cette phrase exprime le sentiment que je veux. Ce que je  cherche est quelque chose qui veut dire que je serai dans le jardin, pour tripoter des choses, en ne faisant rien de particulier, peut-être avec le but de tuer du temps. Le « sans but » est clé ici. En anglais, ça serait

> If you need me, I'll be busying myself in the yard."

Concrètement, est-ce que le verbe « s'occuper »  marche ici, ou y en a-t-il un autre qui convient davantage ?

**Edit**: je crois avoir trouvé ce que je voulais avec [s'affairer](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/s%27affairer).

Comment: If for you "busying myself" could be replaced by "pottering about" then *bricoler* would be my choice (that's how I use the word anyway!). Bien sûr *je vais m'occuper* is fine. Bien que je pense "je serai occupé dans le jardin" serait mieux.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=y+en+a-t%2Cy%27en+a-t&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cy%20en%20a%20-%20t%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cy%27en%20a%20-%20t%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cy%20en%20a%20-%20t%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cy'en%20a%20-%20t%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @MichelT Click the spoon!

Comment: @MichelT Cliquer le lien doit produire la page recherche Google, non ? C'est dans cette page que l'icône de lancement (« cuillère ») doit être cliquée.

Comment: @LPH Merci, LPH.

Comment: @LPH Il m'a fallu un moment pour comprendre de quoi tu parlais. Cette « cuillère / *spoon* » est en fait une loupe : , un symbole assez universel pour signifier « rechercher » dans les interfaces graphiques.

Comment: Honnêtement je trouve qu'occuper fonctionne parfaitement. Sinon, si le tripotage n'est pas trop important, il y a *se tourner les pouces* qui pourrait mettre l'attente plus en valeur.

Comment: It is not a great idea to ask for translation into French of what clearly is on the edge of being idiomatic in English. The English sentence is far from natural sounding.

Comment: to busy oneself with [something]

Comment: busy oneself with = s'occuper à faire quelque chose.

Comment: @Lambie Certes, mais personne ne va pas dire "Je vais m'occuper à faire quelque chose dans le jardin".

Answer (score 2):

Si tu veux dire que tu t'occupes mais sans but particulier, *t'affairer* n'est pas exactement le bon verbe car il implique souvent un travail précis, consciencieux et généralement productif. Je te conseillerais plutôt *bricoler* qui, dans la phrase suivante, peut signifier faire des bricoles, des trucs variés et sans grande importance ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bricoler) Sens **I.-**, **A.-**, **1.**), et donc pas du bricolage (Sens  **I.-**, **A.-**, **2.**).

> Si tu as besoin de moi, je serai dans le jardin à bricoler.